# Complex numbers problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm trying to use the relevant rules and definitions but making little progress.

[image: Here is the question:]

Comment: Follow the hint, simplify the expression to one that only contains $x$ and $y$, then compare real parts and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify it in $x,y$ you get two parts i.e. two equations and it's done. $(x+iy)(1+x-iy)+\frac{5.(x).(1+2i)}{5}-2x-4=0+0i$ now we have two equations. The imaginary part and real part ie $(x+x^2+y^2)+x-2x-4=0$ and $ y+xy+2x=0$ two equations two unknowns solve for $x,y$ and you are done with it.

Comment: But see the first bracket why do you think so.

Comment: You can always edit if am algebrically wrong.!

Comment: It's simpler: $x^2+y^2-4=0$ for the real part and $y+2x=0$ for the imaginary part. So the solutions are the intersection of a circle and a line.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

If $z = x + iy,$ then

1. $\overline{z} = x - iy$
2. $Re(z) = x$
3. $Im(z) = y$

Then, since the right side of the equation is zero, both the real part and imaginary part of the left size must be zero.

Comment: hey imaginary $z$ should be $(-y)$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I don't think that's correct.  [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImaginaryPart.html)

Comment: its $Im(iz)=i.iy=-y$

Comment: I was giving hints, and stopped short of evaluating the expression in the problem.  And besides, $Im(iz) = x$, not $-y$.

Comment: **John** is correct. $\text{Im}(iz) = \text{Im}(i(x+iy)) = \text{Im}(-y+ix) = x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $z=a+bi$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

$$z\left(1+z^{*}\right)+\frac{5\Im\left(iz\right)}{1-2i}-2\Re\left(z^{*}\right)-4=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z\left(1+z^{*}\right)-(1-2i)\Re(z)-4=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$zz^{*}-(1-2i)\Re(z)+z-4=0$$